# How can I disable direct file access by apache from my webserver running on Cent OS using .htaccess file?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, php

From my site root, I have crucial non-php files which I don't want them accessible via url, ie, I don't want someone to access my **names.txt** file after visiting `mysite.tld/names.txt`.
How do I disable the file, and others of any extension from being accessed via http(s)? 
Can we have a `<filesmatch>` directive of sort to only allow access to php extension? 
I'm avoiding using 
`<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>`
 
because I want a dynamic solution to work on all my virtual hosts.

Comment: Its always possiblr to work arround something like this (eg by using a script)  but 1 splution could be to use mod_rewrite to rewrite urls with thise extensions.

Comment: What are the files crucial to/for? Could they be stored outside of the web root? If they need to be accessed by PHP a modified `include_path` would allow them to easily be "visible".